# android stopwatch/timer app - switching back to app when time runs out

Tags: java, android, service, timer, stopwatch

I'm developing an app, as mentioned in title. I need somehow to manage that application will be running/counting time even when user starts/switches to another application. Well, as I learned from another discussion at stackoverflow.com, there is no need to create service that works in background and pointlessly burden processor with counting time when app is not active.

Everything what is needed to be done is to store current time when user switch to another app, compare it to time when he switches back and update the UI according to difference between these times. That's for stopwatch mode. When in timer mode, I need to automatically switch back to application according to time, that is app's UI showing when going o background. What could be the best solution suitable for this and can you give me please some simple examples for this?

Comment: What's problem with service???service is better way to doing this.

Comment: Service is for long-running processes in background, isn't it? I just need to switch back to application after time runs out and show some alert window or play sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So use AlarmManager**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            //call function where you want
            timeout();
  }

public void timeout()
{       //time in milliseconds 1 minute
        Long time = new GregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()+60*1000; //i.e.60*1000=1minute
        // create an Intent and set the class which will execute when Alarm triggers, here we have
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,time, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,1,  intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));

    }
}
```

**Here is broadcast class:**

```
 public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
     @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
                // show dialog or what you want

         }

}
```

**Don't forgot to edit AndroidMainfest:**

```
 //permission
 <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
 //our receiver
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReciever"/>
```

Comment: And in AlarmReciever class I'm supposed to write code for switching back to application, by startactivity() method?

Comment: Yes you can switch activity or display dialog directly or play some sound or what you want...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) for that. `AlarmManager` allows you to schedule tasks and get notified when they are fired.